# Derivatives in positive and negative x directions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, nonstandard-analysis

For a function $f(x)$ the definition of its derivative is $$f'(x) = \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}.$$

The derivative $f'(x)$ is supposed to be the same for $\Delta x>0$ and $\Delta x<0$. Which means that if we now set $\Delta x>0$, $$\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x-\Delta x)-f(x)}{-\Delta x}$$ needs to be true.

**But how do you show that the above expression is true?**

I thought of the example where $f(x)=e^x$, and let $\Delta x=3$. At the point $x=0$, 
$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{e^3-1}{3}$$and$$\frac{f(x-\Delta x)-f(x)}{-\Delta x}=\frac{e^{-3}-1}{-3}.$$
They are not equal and intuitively I thought that as $\Delta x \to 0$, they will **approximately** equal to each other but never exactly equal, since the graph of $f(x)=e^x$ is not symmetrical about $x=0$.

**Is the statement that the derivative is independent of the sign of $\Delta x$, ie the statement $$\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x-\Delta x)-f(x)}{-\Delta x}$$ just an approximation then?**

Comment: Hint: for the "negative" direction, instead of
$$
\frac{f(x-\Delta x) - f(x)}{-\Delta x}
$$
I would write
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(x-\Delta x)}{-\Delta x}
$$
which better reflects the direction of the slope.

Comment: @MattiP. the $\Delta x$ below in your second expression should not have a negative sign then, if the $\Delta x $ itself is positive.

Comment: The main problem here is that $\Delta x=3$ is too large. The growth rate of this function changes too quickly. Try $\Delta x= 0.1$ to see what you wanted to see. Another problem is that you seem to think $f(0)=0$. But in fact $f(0)=e^0=1$.

Comment: If the derivative of f as you approach x from from the right weren't equal to the derivative as you approach x from the left, the function would have a sharp kink in it (it wouldn't be differentiable at that point) and $f'(x)$ would be discontinous at x. For your example of $f(x) = e^x$, $f'(x) = e^x$ is definitely continuous.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks, I edited my question.

Comment: @DavidDiaz thanks for the answer, but I would like to understand it from a more fundamental point of view where one views the derivative as the slope between points $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ where $\Delta x$ becomes small. In this case, the slope between $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ and slope between $x-\Delta x$ and $x$ should not equal, no matter how small $\Delta x$ is. They can only be approximately equal.

Comment: @Taenyfan Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is equal is the limit indeed

$$\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{e^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}=1$$

and

$$\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x-\Delta x)-f(x)}{-\Delta x}= \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{e^{-\Delta x}-1}{-\Delta x}=\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac1{e^{\Delta x}}\frac{e^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}=1$$

Comment: thank you, I understand that the limits equal. Do you know how to show that the two limits will equal for any continuous function $f(x)$?

Comment: Recall that continuity is not sufficient (e.f. |x| at x=0). For f differentialble it can be shown by a change of variable. As an alternative recall the geometrical meaning of the derivative as the slope of the tangent at a point, and if f is differentiable the slope of the secant line approaches the same value from both sides.